# Delphi 10.3 MIDAS AppServer Custome Procedure

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have created a basic DataSnap Server . **File** -> **New** -> **Other** -> **DataSnap** -> **DataSnap Server**.

On the DataSnap Server Wizard I went with following options .

```
[x] Windows
[x] Forms Application
[x] VCL Application
[x] Protocols TCP/IP , Server Methods Class , Sample Methods
[x] TCP/IP Port 32900
[x] TDSServerModule
```

Then I have added to the ServerMethods1 a Database Connection a Query and a DataSetProvider.

On the Client a Android Device I have added
DSProviderConnection1
SQLConnection1
and a ClientDataSet .

**This works wonderfully . Just to confirm that DataSnap Server and Client Communicate .**

Now I wanted to Execute a Stored Procedure from the Client .

So on the Server I created under ServerMethods1 a public procedure .

```
procedure DEVICE_STATUS( ID,UserName,SSID : string; SignalStrength,BatteryLevel : integer);
```

This is obviously on for testing ...

```
procedure TServerMethods1.DEVICE_STATUS( ID,UserName,SSID : string; SignalStrength,BatteryLevel : integer);
begin
  Form1.Edit1.Text:=ID;
end;
```

Back on the Android Phone I have tried

```
NEBULA.AppServer.DEVICE_STATUS('N-01','-','-',0,0);
```

But I get a error IAppServer does not contain a member named 'DEVICE_STATUS' . What am I missing here ?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like I forgot one very simple thing . On the Android Client . Right click on SQLConnection1 and Generate DataSnap Client Classes.....

Comment: Do you mean you found the solution? If you did, either delete your question or enter the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solution :

On the Android client after setting up the SQLConnection , right click on it and click on Generate Datasnap Client Classes. Save the unit . Add this unit to the uses clause where you want to execute the procedure and then .

```
procedure TMainScreen.btnStatusClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Temp : TServerMethods1Client;
begin
  SQLConnection1.Connected:=true;

  Temp := TServerMethods1Client.Create(SQLConnection1.DBXConnection);
  try
    Temp.DEVICE_STATUS('N-01','-','-',0,0);

  finally
    Temp.Free;
  end;
end;
```